# Attitude measurements with digital sensors falling out of synch

Tags: microcontroller, imu, mems

I am just starting to use digital inertial sensors (9 axis: accelerometers, gyros and magnetometers).  Each 3 axis sensor has a sampling frequency I can set so that data goes into a FIFO and I can get 100% of the readings and perform my attitude calculations.

Even if I set up the sensors to the same sampling rate, they will all run at slightly different rates (independent clocks) and will fall out of synch (they run for months at a time, and their oscillators are internal/uncontrollable).

What is the optimal algorithm/solution for updating my attitude when my sensors are FIFO buffered like this and the data is coming in at different rates?

For contraints: I can't use a 9DoF sensor, so I'm stuck using the three independent packages.  If someone suggests synching with a precision clock or something, that is not a solution; just assume that sampling for each sensor is at a regular, independent rate and uncontrollable.  One example device is the [L3GD20](http://www.pololu.com/file/0J563/L3GD20.pdf)

Comment: You don't mention your problem, I assume that you 'need' the sensor data that refers to a specific point in time? Sounds like an interpolation job to me.

Comment: I do mention my problem: "What is the optimal algorithm/solution for updating my attitude when my sensors are FIFO buffered like this and the data is coming in at different rates?"  I need optimal attitude measurements and I have data coming in at different rates.  To put it another way: how do you do data fusion with data from sensors that are sampled at different rates, and those rates are outside of your control, and stored in a FIFO so you can't time stamp them?  e.g. if I get 2.315 accelerometer readings per 1 gyro reading, how do I update my attitude optimally?

Answer (score 1):

I have worked quite extensively in the area with 9d0f boards and let me say that it is possible to sync devices, it's just a matter of how you decide to implement your solution. The L3GD20 device that your refer to has like most other gyroscopes by ST a mode called bypass.

***In Bypass mode, the FIFO is not operational and for this reason it remains empty. As
described in
Figure 7
below, for each channel only the first address is used. The remaining
FIFO slots are empty. When new data is available, the old data is overwritten.***

Why is this mode useful?
Well let's say that you sample an accelerometer, immediately after you can sample your gyroscope and here's the key part.. Even if you gyroscope hasn't had a chance to update its own values you will get the previous sampled reading of your gyroscope which will be a close enough **estimate** and thus alleviates the time sync problem.

In most cases the procedure should be:
Sample all sensors.
Perform attitude calculation.
Then repeat.

Bypass mode in your Gyro allows you to do this and you won't need to worry about time syncing an FIFO readings or the like.

Personally I'd recommend you use interrupts. If this isn't possible you'll need a delta timer to determine the period of time that has passed between samples so your attitude calculation is correct.

There are many fusion algorithms and to discuss them in depth will be extensive.
Some of them include:
Kalman Filters.
Complementary Filters
Sebastian Madgwick/Robert Mayhony’s IMU AHRS algorithm with a demonstration and source that can be found [here](http://www.x-io.co.uk/open-source-imu-and-ahrs-algorithms/)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.  Bypass mode is what I am using now, and it does get the job done.  But I'm looking for an optimal solution: if I sample all sensors and update, I'm limited to the slowest sampling sensor. I'm looking for an algorithm that can take advantage of 100% of the sensor information, on the assumption this may be more complicated but more accurate.  I think the extended kalman might be the right track, but I want to hear from people that have used it.  I'll def keep this in mind going fwd, and thanks for the link!

Comment: That is correct. The slowest sensor will be your limitation. Don't forget though you'd need some seriously fast controller to do all the attitude calculations and any filtration. It will get even more difficult at fast sample rates and you may run into other problems like an interrupt trigger happening before you've even completed the previous attitude calculation. I think above 200Hz get's really difficult on a standard microcontroller...Doing this at 760 Hz (The max speed of your gyro) will be will be amazing if you can pull it off but insanely difficult. By all means give it a try!!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't directly addressed this, but it might well be in an upgrade path in a current design, so I have thought about it.

It's going to depend on your exact needs/wants of course, but here's the rough approach I've laid out in my head.

1. determine the relative sampling rates by the interval between interrupts on each device. You may need this info for data processing.
2. look at the time relationships between the interrupts on different devices.
3. When the relationships between the inter-device interrupts change by some pre-determined amount, just restart/reinitialize the data streams to resynch.

Another approach would be to embrace the differences between the devices, and simply deal with them!  Service each FIFO separately, time stamp the FIFO-full interrupts to your system, and have a resample riding on top of all that. If there's a decimate in this process, you may need to prefilter to prevent aliasing. You'll still need to determine the exact sampling rates for each device.

Each has its high points and low points.  With the latter, the calcs will be exact, but you might reach a point where there's no time to unload one of the buffers, and still do your processing. You would probably need to think about all the ramifications of double buffering or overrunning a ring buffer, and you may still end up needing to restart every now and again.

Or, maybe you can come up with a supervisory system that determines which sensor's interrupt needs to be dealt with first -- in other words, if the interrupts start out coming ABC, what happens if after drift they're coming CAB?  It MIGHT be enough to just run your algorithm as "process whatever three interrupts come, and then do the processing", with an overseer to make sure that if the processing time gets short you just process 4 interrupts to shift the processing to a more opportune time to see if you can get more room.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm not a mathematician, just an electrical engineer, so my answer here is a bit hand wavy. I have published papers dealing with MEMs dead reckoning though, including one specifically about a device using discrete sensors.

Processing the data streams asynchronously will be rather difficult, but not impossible. You'll need to design a fairly complex [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) to deal with the example you gave in your comment "2.315 accelerometer readings per 1 gyro reading" (more specifically an asynchronous Kalman filter). For instance, one of those intermediate accelerometer readings would need to use predicted gyroscope values based on the rotational velocity measured at the previous gyroscope sample and the time difference to the current accelerometer measurement. To maintain any sort of accuracy you would need to adjust that calculation when the new gyroscope measurement is received. You can think of this as having three independent data streams which you are interpolating and when you have a measurement or interpolated value for a particular instant in time, you calculate your new orientation based on the previous orientation. It's important to note that this is just a good way to think of it; linear interpolation will not work well at all. You'll need to use an extended Kalman filter (likely modified for asynchronous operation).

Otherwise, the simplest solution to having your data synchronized is to buffer results until you have a complete set from each of the sensors. So instead of interpolating you'd be decimating. The problem you'll run into with this is a loss in accuracy due to presuming all samples to be from a single point in time. This will not matter too much depending on what average sampling rate this turns out to be and how quickly the device will be changing attitude. For instance, your gyro has a "data ready" signal, you can wait for all such signals from your sensors before reading the complete data set from that time period.

That being said, your real problem is not going to be synchronizing data, it is going to be keeping an accurate orientation estimation for *months* at a time. Without a way to update your system occasionally your calculated position is going to drift *very* quickly (with a system built using the COTS device you've given an example of, you'll likely need an update rate in the order of minutes). That, of course, depends on your device and the system it's in. This wasn't in your question though, so we'll have to leave it at that.

Comment: Decimating SHOULD BE preceded by low-pass filtering to avoid aliasing.  Unless you're suggesting that the contents of the FIFO buffer be averaged together and used as one point, but that's not formally decimation.  That said, I assumed above that if the needed sample rate were low enough to do that, that the user would simply poll the devices in a single-sample fashion, and not worry at all about clock synchro between devices.  The method you suggest might be more effective for anti-aliasing purposes though.

Comment: You are correct, the way I've described it is not technically decimation. I should have noted that I was describing the situation where the OP suggests that the sampling rate for the devices can be set to approximately the same value. In that case, waiting for all samples to be ready without low-pass filtering first would not result in aliasing. For your suggestion of filtering first for higher rates, a simple moving average would likely suffice.